# Observables code never get executed

Tags: angular, typescript

I dont know why the code is not running.
Even the console.log('1') never appears.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getContacts();
    this.getClients();
  }

  getContacts(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get('/api/contacts')
      .map((res: any) => res.json()).flatMap((contacts: any[]) => {
        if (contacts.length > 0) {
          console.log(1);
          const observables = Observable.forkJoin(
            contacts.map((contact: any) => {
              return this.http.get('/api/client/' + contact.company_name)
                .map((res: any) => {
                  let company_name: any = res.json();
                  contact.company_name = name;
                  console.log(contact.company_name);
                  return contact;
                });
            })
          );
          console.log(observables);
          return observables;
        }
        return Observable.of([]);
      }
    );
  }
```

The plain response of localhost:4200/api/contacts is:

```
[{"_id":"59f43f363a2fc421c00ad8b2","anrede":"sir","titel":"dr.","vorname":"name1","nachname":"surname1","company":"59f43f0e3a2fc421c00ad8b0","__v":0},{"_id":"59f43f443a2fc421c00ad8b3","anrede":"mrs","titel":"prof.","vorname":"name2","nachname":"surname2","company":"59f43f1a3a2fc421c00ad8b1","__v":0}]
```

The plain response of localhost:4200/api/client is:

```
{"_id":"59f43f1a3a2fc421c00ad8b1","name":"company2","street":"street 2","zipcode":"45678","city":"city2","__v":0}
```

I followed [this](http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/#respond)

Comment: You never *subscribe* to the observable `getContacts` returns...

Comment: I searched deep in the questions. The topic is duplicated but the first questions title is realy bad, that you will never find it with any of my key words. The title should be edited like mine. I got banned for this....

Comment: Why does the title need to be edited? Now this one is a signpost to the same information. Which was in the framework docs all along anyway; you could have just not asked the question.

Comment: I already said it, the author didnt used the important keyword "observables", which is very important...

Comment: Yes, and now you have used that word, and the duplicate banner links visitors through. *That's the point of flagging duplicates.* See e.g. https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: And I am banned because of this question.

Comment: That's not how bans work. If you have any further issues, see the [help] or [meta].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the `http` module to make the rest call you must add `subscribe` to it.

In your case this would be :

```
this.getContacts().subscribe((data) => {//do something with data})
```